# How to get full file path?

Tags: vb.net

I need to get VS application path.

Hi! In my windows forms application I had added a image file. 
Now I want to get the full path of this image file.
Any idea how can i implement it?

Comment: Where did you add the image file? Did you add it as a resource to your project? In that case, it won't have a path. You use it as a resource, not as a file on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cody Gray pointed out, if you have added the image as a resource, you can access it in code via the applicable image property in the `My.Resources` class.

However, if you have added the image file as just a regular file included in your project, you need to set its "Copy to Output Directory" property to either "Copy if newer" or "Copy Always".  That way, the file will be copied to your project's bin folder when it is built.  Then your code can find it by looking in the executable folder.  You could just assume it's in the current directory, but it would be safer to use something like `system.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` to get the full path.